# Finding Filename only and not entire path VBA Mac Office 2011

Tags: vba, filenames

So I have a macro running, however it currently loops through column A to find the pull filename path (i.e. Macintosh HD:Users:username:path:to:filename). I want it to just find the filename only and not the full path. The path will constantly change so it has to have a way of just extracting the filename only. I have looked at using GetFileName, however I am using Mac Office 2011 so I am having issue getting that to work. Any ideas?

```
Sub CSVauto()
'
' CSVauto Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+x
'
'   Declaring and setting variables for choosing CSV to import
    Dim csvFileName As Variant


''Prompt window to choose csv file
csvFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="")
If csvFileName = False Then Exit Sub
'Setting a variable to find Experimental form name in Data Summary
Dim whatToFind As String 'Declaring that variable
    If Right(csvFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then
        whatToFind = Replace(csvFileName, ".csv", "")
        MsgBox (whatToFind)
    End If
'Looping through A column to find csvFileName without .csv extension
Set cell = Range("A:A").Find(What:=whatToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, _
       LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False)

If Not cell Is Nothing Then
      cell.Select
   End If
```

adding

```
Dim whatToFind As String 'Declaring that variable
Dim NoCsv As String
    If Right(csvFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then
        NoCsv = Replace(csvFileName, ".csv", "")
        whatToFind = Replace(NoCsv, ThisWorkbook.Path, "")‹
```

This gives a partial path so instead of the full path it is just :FolderonDesktop:FolderofCSV:Filename

I thought it would give me just filename, but at least I was able to chop off part of it. Now I just need to get rid of two levels and I will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `InStrRev` to find the index of the last occurrence of `\` in the file path and the use `Mid` or `Right` to return the filename portion of the file path.

---

[image]

```
Function getFileName(FilePath As String) As String

    getFileName = Mid(FilePath, InStrRev(FilePath, "\") + 1)

End Function
```

### MAC

```
Function getFileName(FilePath As String) As String

    getFileName = Mid(FilePath, InStrRev(FilePath, "/") + 1)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: When I add this into macro I keep getting error that it expects an End sub, when I have one at the end. I added your code but replace "\" with ":" because I am working with a Mac so the directory structure is different. Any idea if this will work with a mac?

Comment: I did, which by some research looks like I can't do that with funtions, do I create an entirely different macro for the function? sorry not familiar with functions.

Comment: A function is a macro that returns a value.  Functions and Subs cannot be nested inside each other.  Inside your sub you could use this instead `NoCsv = Mid(csvFileName, InStrRev(csvFileName, "/") + 1)`

Comment: Bingo!!! That works wonderfully. I just had to replace "/" with ":" due to macs reporting that file path type. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help.